# Sort across multiple variables acting as rows in a Matrix table with column rows switched

Tags: powerbi, survey

I created a Matrix table and my column headers are from the values of a single variable, let's call it Wireless Provider.  So I have columns for ATT/Verizon...etc.  My rows are actually 66 different variables that give the appearance of individual rows based on the switch I did in the matrix settings and the client requirement.  But now that the table is set like this I can no longer sort by pressing any drop down because it doesn't show up anymore.  And every solution I can find or Chat GPT tells me is that I Should create a rank column, but it keeps telling me to create 1 rank based on the numeric field that needs sorted.  So this isn't right because I need to sort across all 66 values.... I also need the ability to sort any of the columns, not just ATT for example.